# How to upgrade Ubuntu 9.10 to 12.10 via terminal?

Tags: 12.10, upgrade, 9.10

I am using EEEpc 1000ha.

I can't boot from USB drive, it goes directly to the GRUB dual boot interface (with native WinXP), Also I can't install that boot helper in Windows, not enough disk space. It would be simpler for me to go in the Terminal, I edited `sources.list` to point to the old-releases mirrors. I do `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` it tells me that it is up to date. What would solve my problem?

My `sources.list` (I lost the original):

```
# Required
deb http:// old-releases.ubuntu. com/ubuntu/ karmic main restricted universe multiverse
deb http:// old-releases.ubuntu. com/ubuntu/ karmic-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http:// old-releases.ubuntu. com/ubuntu/ karmic-security main restricted universe multiverse

# Optional
deb http:// old-releases.ubuntu. com/ubuntu/ karmic-backports main restricted universe multiverse
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An upgrade from Ubuntu 9.10 to 12.10 is too much of an effort. Most of the packages will have been updated/upgraded. Chances of breakage are too much. Please save all the important files/documents and install a fresh copy of Ubuntu 12.10. It would be better to install 12.04 because it has a long term support.

As to the problem of not being able to boot from USB, press ESC or F12 or some such button to get into BIOS. It is shown while booting how to get into BIOS.

Regards

"Here's how you boot from the stick: after pressing the power button, the F2 key should be pushed a couple of times to get into the eeePC's BIOS menus. The "quick boot" under the Boot tab should be disabled. Use F10 to save the setting and then as the Netbook reboots hold down the ESC key."

Comment: +1 for 'too much of an effort'. A clean install is the better way to go.